# How QFileSystemModel setRootPath to another drive on linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qfilesystemmodel

I have a drive labeled as "Local Data" mounted at "/media/Local Data".
And my program directory is also in "/media/Local Data/Programming".
I would like to set "Local Data" to be the root path of a QFileSystemModel.
I cannot find a way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
QFileSystemModel* model = new QFileSystemModel;
model->setRootPath("/media/Local Data");

QTreeView tree;
tree.setRootIndex(model->index("/media/Local Data");
tree.setModel(model);
qDebug() << QDir::currentPath();
// "/media/Local Data/Files/Programming/C++/build-FileSystemModel-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Debug"

tree.setMinimumSize(900,500);
tree.show();
```

I get the error `QAbstractItemView::setRootIndex failed : index must be from the currently set model`.

When I run the program, it always give me the root "/" as the root path.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is not related to the `QFileSystemModel`. You haven't set a model for the view. Try this (untested).

```
QFileSystemModel* model = new QFileSystemModel;
model->setRootPath("/media/Local Data");

QTreeView* tree = new QTreeView;
tree->setModel(model);
tree->setRootIndex(tree->model()->index(QDir::currentPath()));
```

Comment: Oh. I did done the setModel just not shown in my question. I will edit it.

Comment: I discover what I did wrong. `setModel()` need to be done before `setRootIndex()`